# GCP PHP Move Uploaded File doesn't works

Tags: php, apache, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I used vm instance on GCP with CentOS v7. It should easy to use `move_uploaded_file`, but I got permission denied

```
[Mon Mar 11 11:47:57.298785 2019] [php7:warn] [pid 22024] [client ***] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(/var/www/html/web-apps/images/menu/19692265_b8533716-e201-49fe-916e-ae993c89fffb_500_500.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/web-apps/back_end/editMenu.php on line 21, referer: http://***/web-apps/pages/activity/editMenu.php?id=18
[Mon Mar 11 11:47:57.298834 2019] [php7:warn] [pid 22024] [client ***] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php79PbIY' to '/var/www/html/web-apps/images/menu/19692265_b8533716-e201-49fe-916e-ae993c89fffb_500_500.jpg' in /var/www/html/web-apps/back_end/editMenu.php on line 21, referer: http://***/web-apps/pages/activity/editMenu.php?id=18
```

I have trying to

1. chown -R apache:apache web-apps/
2. chmod -R 755 web-apps

here are `ls -l`

```
drwxr-xr-x.  3 apache apache    188 Mar 11 09:18 images
```

`ps -aux | grep httpd` for PID 22024

```
apache   22024  0.0  0.3 611668 14348 ?        S    10:23   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

Running this bellow script

```
<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>
```

and result *apache*

`/tmp` folder

```
drwxrwxrwt.  13 apache apache 4096 Mar 11 11:56 tmp
```

What I missed here? Does it possible related with security policy that running on GCP?

Comment: I think, you should give ownership of `www-data` to your directory, with write permission,

Comment: @harishsharma `www-data` is not for `centOs` environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of head-scratch, the problem comes from SElinux.

in **CentOS** 6 above should be **SELinux** enable enforcing

```
setenforce Permissive
```

check the status

```
sestatus
```

refer to https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux